# excel: How to visualize a three variable formula?

Tags: excel, graph, formula

I'm having the hardest time deciding how to properly (if there is such a thing) display in Excel cells and a chart a three variable formula like this:

f(x) = Q*(a+bY+cZ)/a

where the unknowns are Q, Y and Z. Ive tried:
a) multiple tables with the same two variables
b) one table with a user provided value and calculated increases for row and column

but none of these can lead me to one graph (of any dimension) that I can see how each of the three variables change the outcome if the other two stay the same.

Is that even possible ?

Comment: If you want to depict a formula with three unknown then you cannot (obviously) use a two-dimensional graph such as a table / column / line graph. You will need a three-dimensional graph such as a surface. Have a look into your Excel tool-bar and look for three-dimensional graphs. Not many out there as they as such graphs have a tendency to overwhelm people and not give you much insights in return. But there are some...

Comment: Hi Ralph. I do understand that for the graph I will need a surface. However, how do I build the data for the surface? The help files I have found and various examples online only show a two dimentional array represented, like this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Present-your-data-in-a-surface-chart-1050ffc6-6143-4ee7-82b3-421bea88a1e8 However that is not a table that shows a three variable formula. So how does one create values for three variables that can then pass to a surface graph ?

Comment: Maybe the following can be of help in that respect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUoo_7KQfO0 (you can mute the video if you prefer). It's a very simple formula with three variables and shows you in detail how to create it. The formula is different but should be a good and simplistic basis for what you are searching for.

Comment: Hello Ralph. Notice that in this video, the formula is two variables, not three like in my question. Two variables I can handle, my question is specifically for a good visualization of three variables. To make it clearer, in the video you mentioned, she ploted a, z = x2 + y2. I want something for z = x2 + y2 + o2

Comment: In that case you are looking for a four-dimensional chart. I am unaware of any such chart type. Sorry. You might want to give it a try and re-post your question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/. Let me know if they were able to help you by posting the link to your post there here as a comment (like a reference, to show that the two questions / posts are connected).